# TFS 2010 - can Build servers be a VM?

Tags: team-foundation-server, virtual-machines

I'm looking to setup a TFS environment.   I'm proposing the TFS 2010 machine be a virtual box.   can the Build server be a VM?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, yes they can.

Comment: Simple. Authoritative. I like. :)